# Spring MVC - Web Application Design Common Practice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is this common?

```
com.myproject.web.forms 
com.myproject.web.controllers
com.myproject.core.dto
com.myproject.core.service
```

In UserController, 
form is converted to dto, then passed on to the service.

In my case, I would have UserDto and UserForm. Both are almost about exactly the same.

What is Form really used for?

Comment: I wanted to know if the "use of forms" in general is a common practice. In my case right now, I am unable to appreciate the use of it, since the Dto can also be used in the Controller.

Comment: It really depends on what the difference between those is. I suggest looking at the Resource pattern from Spring HATEOAS; that sort of adapter from a Web API onto the internal domain model can help decouple the two APis, but you should examine whether `UserDto` is really necessary or if the app can just use the domain classes directly.

Comment: I probably have to read on "Spring HATEOAS". In my structure, apparently, I have no domain classes.

Comment: How are you actually talking to your database? Usually, you'd have something like `User` which is a JPA Entity or Spring Data Mongo Document, and then `UserDto`/`UserResource` which is a struct class for interaction with external clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case i guess you have use forms to put what would be ui objects (maybe in this case only forms) and separate them from biz objects. i suggest to read n-tier application architecture

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

Comment: Thank you. That confirms my assumption previously.